# -[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc60a690

Tags: iphone, ios5

I think it could cause an error because, I have used layer property of button in several classes. I think this could be the reason but I am not sure.

Now, when I am running my application on iPod after sometime (5 minutes max) the application crashes with the following error message:

```
-[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc60a690
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Post some more code.. How did you allocate the CALayer instance?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because an object has been deallocated and you are trying to send it a message.

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to say what you need to do in order to fix the problem.

I would suggest you read up on memory management in objective-c. For example,

[Apple Documentation for Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

But there are many other documents about it. If you don't understand these concepts, then you are going to have many problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna remove the class self in the current view, and it had have IBOutlets connect with the removed view that you did need to setup the IBOutlets to nil, it still works for me, like this :

```
-(void)backRootController{
    //I wanna change the current viewController to rootViewController on self.tabBarController.
    RootViewController *_rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    NSArray *_viewControllers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
    NSMutableArray *_tabs     = [NSMutableArray array];
    for( UIViewController *_tabViewController in _viewControllers ){
        if( _tabViewController == self ){
            _rootViewController.tabBarItem = _tabViewController.tabBarItem;
            _tabViewController = _rootViewController;
        }
        [_tabs addObject:_tabViewController];
    }
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_tabs];

    //To setup the IBOutlets to nil to avoid [CALayer release] crash. ( UILabel, UIView, UIImageView )
    self.outPreviewLabel           = nil;
    self.outPreviewView            = nil;
    self.outPreviewImageView.image = nil;
    self.outPreviewImageView       = nil;

    //Then remove the view and exchanged current controller.
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
    [_rootViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I think you haven't retained your buttons in your viewDidLoad method, thats why after some time they deallocate. Just add retain at the end where you alloc it or write it in @property..

Comment: Or perhaps learn the correct usage for memory management rather than just scattering retain everywhere even if it isn't appropriate.

Comment: I n not talking like that you put retain everywhere...Check Apple documentation and then tell me i m right or wrong....when u declare any variable in .h class, you have to add its property, but no one use it and then face such problems......

Comment: Your answer says "Just add retain at the end where you alloc it". It's not always appropriate to retain an object when you alloc it. I think you need to read the Apple memory management documentation again first. For example, if you are returning an object from a method then you wouldn't retain it, but you would autorelease it. Likewise if you write a @property you don't always want a retain in there - you might want a copy.

Comment: but if any body not write @property and at runtime any of its object deallocated and app get application is crashed with this error message:-

-[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc60a690 what he need read memory management or answer....

Comment: See my answer correctly i add both case here not tell him to write only retain any where....

Comment: I think you need to read up on `@property` too. That doesn't automatically mean it will handle memory management for you either. It depends what type of parameters you use when defining your property (retain, copy). Don't assume that the examples you have seen cover all of the possibilities unless you read the documentations.